# Search coordinates in a binary not working correctly

Tags: javascript, coordinates, binary-tree

I need to insert a lot of coordinates in a binary tree and sometimes merge them. I'm testing the program for a while and have noted that the search function doesn't work sometimes.

In this example, I created two binary trees, merged them and searched for some coordinate, but the coordinates that are inserted in the tree, were not found:

```
First tree:
0 2
9 8
7 0
6 0
Second tree:
3 2
8 5
4 1
5 6
Merged trees:
3 2
8 5
4 1
5 6
0 2
9 8
7 0
6 0
VALUES 8 and 5 NOT FOUND
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Here is the code:

```
function binarytree()
{
  this.root = null;
  this.add = function()
  {
    var node = {
                 x : j,
                 y : i,
                 left : null,
                 right : null
               };
    var current;
    if (this.root == null) this.root = node;
      else {
             current = this.root;
             while (1)
             {
               if (i < current.y || j < current.x) {
                  if (current.left == null) {
                      current.left = node;
                      break;
                  }
                   else current = current.left;
               }
               else if (i > current.y || j > current.x) {
                       if (current.right == null) {
                           current.right = node;
                           break;
                       }
                       else current = current.right;
                    }
                    else break;
             }
           }
  }

  this.search = function(tree, i, j) {
    var found = false;
    current = tree.root;
    while (!found && current) {
      if (i < current.y || j < current.x) current = current.left;
        else if (i > current.y || j > current.x) current = current.right;
          else found = true;
    }
    return found;
  }

  this.print = function(no)
  {
    if (no)
    {
      this.print(no.left);
      this.print(no.right);
      console.log(no.x, no.y);
    }
  }
}

function merge(tree, tree2) {
    if (tree2.x < tree.x || tree2.y < tree.y) {
        if (tree.left) {
            this.merge(tree.left, tree2);
        } else {
            tree.left = tree2;
        }
    } else {
        if (tree.right) {
            this.merge(tree.right, tree2);
        } else {
            tree.right = tree2;
        }
    }
}
  var i, j;
  var tree = new binarytree();
  var tree2 = new binarytree();

  for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
  {
     i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     tree.add();
  }

  for (x = 0; x < 4; x++)
  {
     i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     j = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     tree2.add();
  }

  console.log("First tree:");
  tree.print(tree.root);
  console.log("Second tree:");
  tree2.print(tree2.root);

  merge(tree.root,tree2.root);
  console.log("Merged trees:");
  tree.print(tree.root);

  if (tree.search(tree, i, j) == true) console.log("FOUND VALUES " + j + " AND " + i);
    else console.log("VALUES " + j + " AND " + i + " NOT FOUND");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already mentioned in your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69355506/binary-k-d-trees-implementation-in-javascript), you need to use KD trees for this, as a normal binary search tree is intended for 1-dimensional values, not 2-dimensional values.

There are several issues in your code:

- The way you split points into 2 categories is not a transitive operation. Let's say you have two points in one tree:  (0, 0) and (10, -5), then the second point will be stored in the `left` property of the root. This is because -5 is less than 0. Now we have a second tree with two points: (4, 4) and also (10, -5). The tree will have the same structure as the first for the same reasons. Your `merge` function will put the second tree in the `right` property of the first tree's root. This is because (4, 4) is considered "right" of (0, 0). Now notice how this is inconsistent: now we have a (10, -5) sitting both in the left and the right subtree of the merged tree! This happens because the way you compare points is not a transitive comparison.
- The above point is the major problem, but also notice that `if (i < current.y || j < current.x)` will on average be true for 75% of the cases. This is a second reason why this comparison method is not the right one.

The way to compare 2D-points in a KD tree is to *alternate* comparisons with either the X-coordinate or the Y-coordinate. So at the top-level of the tree you would compare Y-coordinates to decide whether to go left or right, and on the next level you would compare X-coordinates. Then again one level deeper you would compare Y-coordinates again, ...etc.

Some other remarks:

- Use `class` syntax
- Create a constructor also for the node instances
- Don't print in *methods*, instead define a generator to produce all values, and a `toString` method and print that string in your main program.
- Avoid using global variables: your `add` method should take `i` and `j` as arguments, and you should declare variables always (you didn't use `var current` in `search`, nor for `x` and `y` in the main code): this is crucial if you want to write reliable code. Consider using `"use strict"` which will alert you about such problems.
- `add` and `search` will use a similar way to navigate through the tree, so put the code that they have in common in a separate function, which we could call `locate`.
- As far as I know, there is no way to merge KD trees the way you have imagined it, where you can decide to put the "rest" of the second tree under a leaf node of the first. So I would suggest to just iterate the nodes of the second tree and insert them one by one in the first.

Here is the suggested code:

```js
"use strict"; // To help avoid all kinds of problems

class Node { // Use a class for creating node instances
    constructor(i, j) {
        this.x = i;
        this.y = j;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
    * inorder() { // Generator to visit all nodes
        if (this.left) yield * this.left.inorder();
        yield [this.x, this.y];
        if (this.right) yield * this.right.inorder();
    }
}

class BinaryTree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
    }
    locate(i, j) { // A common function to avoid code repetition
        if (this.root == null) return [null, "root"];
        let current = this.root;
        let axis = "x";
        let otherAxis = "y";
        while (true) {
            // alternate the axis:
            [axis, otherAxis, i, j] = [otherAxis, axis, j, i];
            if (i < current[axis]) {
                if (current.left == null) return [current, "left"];
                current = current.left;
            } else if (i > current[axis] || j != current[otherAxis]) {
                if (current.right == null) return [current, "right"];
                current = current.right;
            } else { // point is already in the tree
                return [current, "equal"]; 
            }
        }
    }
    add(i, j) { // this method should have parameters
        if (this.root == null) {
            this.root = new Node(i, j); // Use constructor for creating node
        } else {
            const [current, side] = this.locate(i, j);
            if (side !== "equal") {
                current[side] = new Node(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    search(i, j) {
        const [_, side] = this.locate(i, j);
        return side === "equal";
    }
    * inorder() {
        if (this.root) yield * this.root.inorder();
    }
    mergeWith(otherTree) {
        // Insert all the other nodes one by one:
        for (let point of otherTree.inorder()) {
            this.add(...point);
        }
    }
    toString() { // Don't print, but produce string
        return JSON.stringify(Array.from(this.inorder()));
    }
}

const tree = new BinaryTree();
for (const point of [[0, 2], [9, 8], [7, 0], [6, 0]]) tree.add(...point);
const tree2 = new BinaryTree();
for (const point of [[3, 2], [8, 5], [4, 1], [5, 6]]) tree2.add(...point);
console.log("First tree:");
console.log(tree.toString());
console.log("Second tree:");
console.log(tree2.toString());
tree.mergeWith(tree2);
console.log("Merged trees:");
console.log(tree.toString());

// Check that all points are found:
for (const point of tree.inorder()) {
    console.log(...point, tree.search(...point));
}
```

Comment: trincot, again and again, thank you! You're so professional! I deleted the question because I thought no one would help me and I received critics for code identation, so I thought this. Thanks so much again! If I can do something for you, you can count with me!